# How do I get the exact error location in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am receiving this error when trying to run a laravel project.

[image]

I would like to know the exact source of the error ie. either in my Controllers/Models/View. How do I do it. 
This is the error source provided. 'Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is from the framework, trying to access a table in the database that does not exist.

- Check your migration if you created a `user_view` table
- Run `php artisan migrate` if you did not already done that.
- Check your `.env` file for the Database connection, if you are connecting to the correct database.
- In your model add `protected $table = 'user_view';` if you are not following the Laravel code style.

Answer (score 1):

Check your model, if table is initialized in the model, or table exists in your DB.
In Laravel **Query Exception** is responsible for throwing errors, if there is any problem in the query.

All database operations handle by Model, so you don't have to go to view, please check your Model, if the Model is perfect then please check if you are using the correct name in you iteration.